# can't figure out sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Could someone please help me. I'm trying to create an xml list with all the events ordered by date. I'm doing this by using a php script. Right now I have this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(K.kalender_datum,'%W %d %M %Y') as afhaaldag, A.afval_naam
        FROM tblkalender K
        INNER JOIN tblafval A
        ON A.pk_afval_Id = K.fk_afval_Id
        WHERE kalender_datum > CURDATE()
        ORDER BY K.kalender_datum";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$last_date = "";
$tag_open = false;

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$xml .= "<kalender>\n";

for($i = 0; $i<mysql_num_rows($query); $i++)
{   
    $itemrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    if($last_date != $itemrow['kalender_datum'])
    {
        //als de laatste datum die gebruikt is niet gelijk is aan de datum die hij binnen krijgt, moet hij een nieuwe afhaaldag beginnen
        if($tag_open)
        {
            $xml .= "\t</afhaaldag>\n";
            $tag_open = false;
        }
        $xml .= "\t<afhaaldag>\n";
        $xml .= "\t<datum>" . $itemrow['kalender_datum'] . "</datum>\n";
        $xml .= "\t<afval>" . $itemrow['afval_naam'] . "</afval>\n";    
        $last_date = $itemrow['kalender_datum'];
    }   

    else
    {
        $xml .= "\t<afval>" . $itemrow['afval_naam'] . "</afval>\n";
        $last_date = $itemrow['kalender_datum'];
        $tag_open = true;
    }   
}
$xml .= "</kalender>";
echo $xml;
```

That gives me this output in xml:

```
<kalender>
   <afval>Grofvuil</afval>
   <afval>Restafval</afval>
   <afval>GFT</afval>
   <afval>PMD</afval>
   <afval>Snoeiresten</afval>
   <afval>GFT</afval>
   <afval>Restafval</afval>
   <afval>GFT</afval>
   <afval>PMD</afval>
   <afval>GFT</afval>
   <afval>Snoeiresten</afval>
   <afval>Papier en karton</afval>
   <afval>Grofvuil</afval>
   <afval>Restafval</afval>
   <afval>GFT</afval>
   <afval>PMD</afval>
</kalender>
```

But what I need is this:

```
<kalender>
   <afhaaldag>
      <datum>2012-01-02</datum>
      <afval>GFT</afval>
      <afval>Restafval</afval>
      <afval>PMD</afval>
   </afhaaldag>
   <afhaaldag>
      <datum>2012-01-17</datum>
      <afval>Papier en karton</afval>
   </afhaaldag>
   <afhaaldag>
      <datum>2012-01-23</datum>
      <afval>GFT</afval>
   </afhaaldag>
</kalender>
```

Does someone know how I can do it. I know I need some sort of loop (I'm guessing a for loop). Could someone please help me out on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using python here, but you can follow the code without problems:

```
kalender = [
('2012-01-02', 'GFT'),
('2012-01-02', 'Restafval'),
('2012-01-02', 'PMD'),
('2012-01-17', 'Papier en karton'),
('2012-01-23', 'GFT')
] 

last_date = ""
tag_open = False

xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
xml += "<kalender>\n"


for i in kalender:
    # i[0] == datum
    # i[1] == afval

    # i == $itemrow in your code

    datum = i[0]
    afval = i[1]

    if last_date != datum:
        if tag_open:
            xml += "\t</afhaaldag>\n"
            tag_open = False

        xml += "\t<afhaaldag>\n"
        xml += "\t<datum>" + datum + "</datum>\n"
        xml += "\t<afval>" + afval +  "</afval>\n"
        last_date = datum
            tag_open = True
    else:
        xml += "\t<afval>" + afval + "</afval>\n"
        last_date = datum
        tag_open = True
xml += "\t</afhaaldag>\n"
xml += "</kalender>"
print xml
```

And this is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kalender>
    <afhaaldag>
    <datum>2012-01-02</datum>
    <afval>GFT</afval>
    <afval>Restafval</afval>
    <afval>PMD</afval>
    </afhaaldag>
    <afhaaldag>
    <datum>2012-01-17</datum>
    <afval>Papier en karton</afval>
    </afhaaldag>
    <afhaaldag>
    <datum>2012-01-23</datum>
    <afval>GFT</afval>
    </afhaaldag>
</kalender>
```

[Finished]

The output is exact your are looking for, does it? Try to check again, because in your new output the datum tag isnt' there, so that's wierd.

**Notice** I add two extra lines:

```
tag_open = True  ##(in the True part of the If Statement)
xml += "\t</afhaaldag>\n" ###Before ending the kalender tag.
```

**and** remove the if statement in the else clause.

Code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3389104/kal.py

-------End of Edit

My comment (in code):

```
$last_date = "";
$tag_open = false;

for($i = 0; $i<mysql_num_rows($query); $i++)
{   
    $itemrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);   

    if ($last_date != $itemrow['kalender_datum'])  
    {
       //New Entry
       if (tag_open)
       {
           $xml .= "\t</afhaaldag>\n";
           tag_open = false;
       }
       $xml .= "\t<afhaaldag>\n";
       $xml .= "\t<datum>" . $itemrow['kalender_datum'] . "</datum>\n";
       $xml .= "\t<afval>" . $itemrow['afval_naam'] . "</afval>\n";
       $xml .= "\t</afhaaldag>\n";

       $last_date = $itemrow['kalender_datum']
    }
    else
    {
       if not (tag_open)
       {
           $xml .= "\t<afhaaldag>\n";
           tag_open = true;
       }
       $xml .= "\t<afval>" . $itemrow['afval_naam'] . "</afval>\n";
    }
}
```

Excuse some typos, i don't have a pc with php right now. This code is my general idea, i dunno it works.

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow (I'm having some issues with Filezilla, can't connect to server). Thanks!

Comment: ok, I was finally able to test it, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. The code you gave me, gave an error that the tag <afhaaldag> wasn't closed. I managed to fix that, but it isn't completely doing as it is supost to do. I'm now getting this:
<kalender>
<afval>Grofvuil</afval>
<afval>Restafval</afval>
<afval>GFT</afval>
<afval>PMD</afval>
<afval>Snoeiresten</afval>
<afval>Restafval</afval>
<afval>PMD</afval>
<afval>GFT</afval>
<afval>Snoeiresten</afval>
<afval>Papier en karton</afval>
</kalender>
Grofvuil</afval>

I'll edit my original post so you can see my new code.

Comment: Please, see my edited answer with executed code. Try inserting more echo's for debugging.

Comment: thank you SOOO much!!! You're my hero right now :) It were indeed the two missing tags (and the faulty reference after changing the query)

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing off hand I would say is that there isn't a "`kalender_datum`" key in your query result. You alias the formated date to `afhaaldag`. So in your loop you should have:

```
if($last_date != $itemrow['afhaaldag'])
{
    ...
    $xml .= "\t<datum>" . $itemrow['afhaaldag'] . "</datum>\n";
    $xml .= "\t<afval>" . $itemrow['afval_naam'] . "</afval>\n";    
    $last_date = $itemrow['afhaaldag'];
}   

else
{
    $xml .= "\t<afval>" . $itemrow['afval_naam'] . "</afval>\n";
    $last_date = $itemrow['afhaaldag'];
    $tag_open = true;
}
```

Not sure if that is what's wrong as I haven't tested the code, but it could be the issue.

Comment: oh yeah, how dumb of me (*blush) I edited the query, but totally forgot about it (I've got my English exam on mind). I'll try it out tomorrow, I really have to work on my English now. The exam is in less than 12 hours

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I really overlooked that one :)